# Why am I getting "Identifier expected" in VS Code when I use Svelte-grid for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, svelte

I am developing a react application and have installed svelte-grid with NPM --> https://svelte-grid.now.sh/usage

When I try to use the provided example...

```
<Grid cols={3} bind:items={items} let:item={item}>
  <div>{item.id}</div>
</Grid>
```

...I get an error in VS Code saying "Identifier expected" for the colon in `bind:items`and `let:item`.

I have tried adding the "svelte for vs code" extension but I still get the same error. I don't know how to fix this, I have never used svelte before, what should I do to get this working?

Comment: Which is the extension of your file?

Comment: I am trying to use the example in my app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the editor is trying to interpreter your file as JavaScript. You should change the extension of your file in `.svelte`.